# DataGrid with Combo Box Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a datagrid which is bound in xml to a item source. Within this datagrid I have a combo box which has its own item source which is a simple enum.

I want to be able on selectedIndex to update the item source of the parent object so in this case the data grids item source.

```
<DataGrid Margin="10" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TEST">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource enumType}}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

So I have two different Item Sources one for the combo box and one for the data grid, but I want the selected Index of the combo box to update the property "Type" which is part of the data grids item Source "Collection".

Comment: The way you do it, it should update Type property of the current item in the ItemsSource. What kind of results are you getting? Does your combo box dispays the right data?

Comment: The combo box is bound correctly but it does not update the datagrid object, so I dont get an error I just get null in the Collection.

Comment: Do you get some exceptions in your Output?

Comment: no exceptions - It just seems like I am binding incorrectly.....

Comment: Normally, when the binding is not correct, silent exception is thrown and shown in the output. If that is not the case, binding is usually correct...